# visibilty check in google play

Tags: android, software-distribution

It sounds stupid, but this is my situation.
I am living in switzerland and I have an productiv app distributed for USA only.

How can I check if the app is visible for USA Users in Google Play ?

- My Android-devices in switzerland doesn't show the app in googlePlay. I guess because I am in switzerland. -> Makes sence
- In GooglePlay I can't find my app. I guess because GooglePlay detects my location too. -> Makes sence.
- When jump to GooglePlay with directlink https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id= I can see the app, but its not compatible with any devices. -> I guess again, because of location detection.

So how can I be sure, that the app is visible outside of my country, say in USA ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software distribution. Can't you just try using a proxy?

Comment: What do you mean with a proxy ? This is about an Android App. There is also a tag "Software Distribution", which I thought is a good description to the question. I guess the question could be interesting for Android Developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer is to use a proxy of some sort, a free one of Google might do the trick. Another thing you can do is to modify the url like so:

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torque&hl=***en***](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torque&hl=en)

versus

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torque&hl=***ru***](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torque&hl=ru)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I do not understand, what you mean with a proxy. The URL's you provided I guess is only for the languages, but my problem I do not know if the app is visible for USA Users. I could change the language on my device to english, but I still will not see it, because my location is switzerland.

Comment: @user1344545 [Go here](http://hidemyass.com/), now under advanced options selected server, and pick a USA server. Then enter in your app URL.

Comment: THe Hint with the proxy is very helpfull. Thank you. I see now that the App appears in GooglePlay Store from US.

Comment: @user1344545 Glad I could be of assistance!